# What is the purpose of the kotlin/ folder inside an Android apk?

Tags: android, build, kotlin

I've built an Android project with Kotlin support. I've used APK analyser on the resulting APK and noticed it contains a folder named kotlin/ outside classes.dex:

[image]

Looks like there are .class files inside the folder.

Anyone can explain what is the purpose of that folder? Shouldn't all bytecode be translated into .dex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052868/what-are-kotlin-builtins-files-and-can-i-omit-them-from-my-uberjars),

> These files contain data for declarations of standard ("built-in") Kotlin classes which are not compiled to .class files, but rather are mapped to the existing types on the platform (in this case, JVM). For example, kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins contains the information for non-physical classes in package kotlin: Int, String, Enum, Annotation, Collection, etc.

Comment: Why quote an exact answer instead of flagging as a duplicate though?

Comment: May be the answer was similar, but the question seemed to be a little different to me.